# React JS Fetch from multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I can fetch contents from my Django server with which code below.

But I need fetch from also another URL : http://127.0.0.1:8000/userpost/tagpool/

I don't know how to do it. Please help.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/contents/", {
      method: 'GET', 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      }
    })
    .then( resp => resp.json())
    .then( resp => setFeatured(resp))
    .catch( error => console.log(error))
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Promises chaining` or `Chaining`

For example,

```js
// Make a request for user.json
fetch('http://localhost/article/promise-chaining/user.json')
  // Load it as json
  .then(response => response.json())
  // Make a request to GitHub
  .then(user => fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}`))
  // Load the response as json
  .then(response => response.json());
```